# How to get a table from long format data by month and username?

Tags: r

My data frame is like this, it is a long-format dataset. Each username may have many observations.

```
structure(list(username = structure(c(67L, 95L, 58L, 61L, 65L, 
66L, 10L, 2L, 41L, 85L, 29L, 76L, 59L, 77L, 97L, 22L, 96L, 47L, 
74L, 13L, 48L, 78L, 15L, 18L, 71L, 9L, 89L, 50L, 98L, 24L, 14L, 
90L, 64L, 1L, 93L, 62L, 52L, 83L, 88L, 82L, 73L, 8L, 45L, 6L, 
28L, 57L, 7L, 94L, 69L, 20L, 11L, 26L, 42L, 16L, 43L, 4L, 92L, 
70L, 5L, 56L), .Label = c("__aubssss", "_CurlyFryGuy_", "_JLovee", 
"100ProofWoman", "amoodyknapp", "ankushthebest10", "anna_michaux", 
"AnnetteVitelli3", "Bierkast", "Bigfamlife", "bluemoon357", "boogy1228", 
"Brenderzzz_", "brendochendo", "cappir", "CarmelScotsNews", "charlesdlcruz", 
"ChildOUniverse", "CllrKenPollock", "CoastCyclist", "Crampedsultana", 
"Crescen04324237", "CuddiCAPALOT", "d1no_nugget", "damnnndor", 
"danieldurrans", "dbrown13", "ducksandchucks", "EclecticCoding", 
"Felstedboy", "gengen0309", "Herbie555", "Ho8Go8L1N", "Honeylotus333", 
"huegolden", "iamesrvan", "IanSmalley3", "Ipeethree3", "Its_Jack_Brooo", 
"ItsBittie", "Jackie_montes", "james_southcott", "JanJoostBouwman", 
"Just_Jones33", "Karabo_Mtaung", "KathrynwithaY", "Keioney_kisses", 
"kikilovescats", "KLobstar", "LattaZakyra", "lilac_bun", "lizziemonkhouse", 
"m_melodias", "MainMandarin", "marge_cord", "Maverick1914", "May_leita", 
"mcbadlon", "MiyaDior", "msmrocks", "NaazhimSupreme", "napitupulu_a", 
"natashametzler", "Nick_Miles_", "nivanacampos", "nrazaliyah", 
"Ohh_Ziggy", "OnlySimphiwe", "orodelancs", "parrothead34", "PeachiesPromo", 
"PickledGingerBC", "popkis", "preciousrubie", "reverend_thom", 
"RevTinTin", "RudyJb1024", "samanthacraig15", "SandraRPearce1", 
"siempreAM0nae", "simplyaracelii", "SimStrength", "smutwiizard", 
"spaceboosh", "SplendentSweven", "stankloaf", "TaterSaladJD", 
"tayzer6", "terri2kool", "thehulkster", "ThisOffendsMeTV", "undersiegexo", 
"Warrior_Maiden", "WayCatPub", "WEAVYwonder_", "wsrphoto", "xkimmygirlx", 
"Yildiiiiiiiiz"), class = "factor"), positive = c(0.165, 0, 0.34, 
0.06, 0.106, 0, 0.292, 0, 0, 0.059, 0.139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.031, 
0, 0.119, 0, 0.457, 0.192, 0, 0, 0.128, 0.121, 0.101, 0.317, 
0, 0.528, 0.374, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.233, 0.092, 0.079, 0, 0, 0.174, 
0.094, 0.059, 0, 0.093, 0.103, 0.099, 0.097, 0.102, 0, 0.112, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.225, 0.095, 0.213, 0.116, 0.043, 0.078), compound = c(-0.1027, 
-0.3612, 0.5574, -0.886, 0.4738, 0, 0.9277, 0, -0.6077, 0.5023, 
0.5635, 0, 0, -0.4767, -0.8248, -0.4678, -0.296, 0.0094, 0, 0.9274, 
0.6124, -0.6664, 0, 0.6486, 0.6116, 0.5399, 0.8926, 0, 0.6792, 
0.9768, 0, 0.2732, -0.7073, 0.892, -0.7783, 0.3818, 0, -0.6739, 
0.7314, 0.4588, -0.2411, 0, -0.2212, 0.2023, -0.2244, 0.296, 
-0.4417, -0.7003, 0.2946, -0.6808, 0, 0, -0.0387, -0.3816, 0.5106, 
0.296, 0.6739, 0.5487, -0.2023, 0.5229), Date = structure(c(38L, 
38L, 35L, 35L, 30L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 
19L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 7L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 39L, 38L, 30L, 
29L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 21L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 34L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 
39L, 39L, 36L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 
5L, 1L, 24L, 39L, 31L, 31L, 28L), .Label = c("2020-02-02", "2020-02-07", 
"2020-02-08", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", 
"2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-21", 
"2020-02-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-29", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-13", 
"2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", 
"2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", 
"2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-29", 
"2020-03-30", "2020-03-31"), class = "factor"), agegroup = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("MA", 
"OA", "YA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope to generate an output table with a new variable time (added):

If the time falls in Sep 2020 Code 1

If the time falls in Oct 2020 Code 2

If the time falls in Nov 2020 Code 3

If the time falls in Dec 2020 Code 4

If the time falls in Jan 2021 Code 5

If the time falls in Feb 2021 Code 6

If the time falls in March 2021 Code 7

If the time falls in April 2021 Code 8

The data frame will be like:

Each username will have **8** observations, so the new data will have 60*7 rows.

If the username does not have value in a specific time, code NA.
If the username has value(s) in this time frame(month), calculate mean(compound) for these observations.

```
username agegroup time  mean_compound
a          YA       1        NA
a          YA       2        0.5
a          YA       3        NA
a          YA       4        0.1
a          YA       5        0.1
a          YA       6        0.2
a          YA       7        0.2
a          YA       8        NA
```

@arkun Thanks!  I changed your code to

```
 data_meergeed = data_d %>%
  group_by(username, agegroup,
           Date = ceiling_date(ymd(Date), 'month')) %>% 
  summarise(mean_compound = mean(compound), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  complete(username, agegroup,Date = seq(as.Date('2020-09-01'), 
                                         as.Date('2021-04-01'), by = '1 month'))%>%
  mutate(Date = format(Date, '%b %Y'))
```

But I found one username still have multiple reservations

How can I make one username has **8 observations**, which means that for each month they **only have one observation** (calculate the mean)?

Comment: what of `Feb 2020`?

Comment: Is the expected ouptut correct (based on the input data)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
     group_by(username_agegroup = agegroup, 
      Date = ceiling_date(ymd(Date), 'month')) %>% 
    summarise(mean_compound = mean(compound), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    complete(username_agegroup, Date = seq(as.Date('2020-09-01'), 
             as.Date('2021-04-01'), by = '1 month'))%>%
    mutate(Date = format(Date, '%b %Y'))
```